# Can static Array Initialisation be 'overloaded'?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have these statements, more specific an array declaration of MyDouble objects and a regular MyDouble object initialisation :

```
MyDouble D[8]; //Creating 8 'MyDouble' objects (created with default constructor)
MyDouble t;
```

The main goal is I want to call a different constructor for the MyDouble objects created in the array *D* as opposed to the MyDouble *t*. The above statements cannot be modified.

My question is if it is possible to get into the initialization process which C++ now does automatically? Can I overload this initialization process lets say by putting some kind of function in MyDouble class (overloading `operator[]` or something similar)?

I guess this is not possible, I just wanted some feedback on this. I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: You are calling the default constructor both times. There is no way to call a "different default constructor" each time.

Comment: So you can change `MyDouble` but not the declaration of the variables?

Comment: Why would you want to do it (with these given restrictions)?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. (considering your restraints)

Answer (score 2):

From 8.5p6,

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means: [...]
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized; [...]

So the initialization performed on array elements is the same as that performed on a lone object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to call a different constructor on the array as follow:

```
MyDouble D[8] = {
    MyDouble( 1 ),     // Create from an int
    MyDouble( "2.0" ), // Create it from an string
    MyDouble( 1.35 ),  // Create from a double
    // rest of the items will be initialized using default constructor
};
```

But if your goal is to call a different constructor for each array, the result is no!

```
MyDouble {
    MyDouble( /* I have nothing to put here to make this the choice for arrays */ );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector` instead of simple array. It will allow you control the process of array element creation with custom `allocator`, or in a simple case, you can copy-construct all your elements from the given one.

```
struct C
{
    C() { std::cout << "Constructed\n";}
    C(const C&) {std::cout << "Copy constructed\n";}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<C> a(8, C()); //al elements are copy constructed
}
```